# How to determine the "sentiment" between two named entities with Python/NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm using NLTK to extract named entities and I'm wondering how it would be possible to determine the sentiment between entities in the same sentence. So for example for "Jon loves Paris." i would get two entities Jon and Paris. How would I be able to determine the sentiment between these two entities? In this case should be something like Jon -> Paris = positive

Answer (score 1):

In short "you cannot". This task is far beyond simple text processing which is provided with NLTK. Such objects relations sentiment analysis could be the topic of the research paper, not something solvable with a simple approach. One possible method would be to perform a grammar analysis, extraction of the conceptual relation between objects and then independent sentiment analysis of words included, but as I said before - it is rather a reasearch topic.